# Gnuplot - How to splot surface and points with dgrid3d

Tags: gnuplot

I have a .dat file that I need to plot as a surface :

```
functionVisu.dat
X   Y     Z
0 -3.9 1.68777
0 -4 1.7568
0 -4.1 1.81828
0 -4.2 1.87158
0 -4.3 1.91617
0 -4.4 1.9516
0 -4.5 1.97753
0 -4.6 1.99369
0 -4.7 1.99992
0 -4.8 1.99616
0 -4.9 1.98245
-0.1 -3.9 1.68277
-0.1 -4 1.75181
-0.1 -4.1 1.81328
-0.1 -4.2 1.86658
-0.1 -4.3 1.91117
-0.1 -4.4 1.94661
-0.1 -4.5 1.97253
-0.1 -4.6 1.9887
-0.1 -4.7 1.99493
-0.1 -4.8 1.99117
-0.1 -4.9 1.97746
-0.2 -3.9 1.66783
-0.2 -4 1.73687
etc
```

But also need to plot points on this surface, the file containing the points (pointVisu.dat) is also XYZ values.
The problem is, with my actual script:

```
set hidden3d
set dgrid3d 50,50 qnorm 2
splot [-10:10][-10:10] "functionVisu.dat" with lines, "pointVisu.dat" with dots lw 10 lc rgb "red"
pause -1
```

the result I am getting is not looking as expected :
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMVhu.png)

My points are spreaded due to the dgrid3d, but I can't manage to make them appear as wanted. Also, with the use of qnorm 2, the points are under the surface function even though they are strict images of it.

[Points under the surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJWr1.png)

I can have the result I want but without using dgrid3d, which gives me a good but not aesthetic result:
[Wanted but bad result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IETi.png)

How could I combinate the render of dgrid3d but with single points displaying properly ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnuplot version 5.4.3 (Dec 2021) introduced a keyword "nogrid" that can be added to the splot command so that points are plotted individually rather being used for a grid. So if your copy of gnuplot is new enough, the answer to one of your questions is shown below (using some other data)

```
set hidden3d
set dgrid3d 25,25 
splot "foo.dat" with lines title "gridded", \
      "foo.dat" with points nogrid pt 7 title "nogrid"
```

[image]

**Fallback for older gnuplot versions**

For older gnuplot versions that do not recognize the `nogrid` keyword there is a work-around.  Not all plot styles can be gridded, and this includes the `with labels` plot style.  But labels can have an associated point, so you can plot a set of non-gridded points by describing them as labels with blank text:

```
splot "foo.dat" using 1:2:3 with lines title "gridded", \
      "foo.dat" using 1:2:3:("") with labels point pt 7 title "nogrid"
```